# Nano in Pathfinder Terminal Shows 2-Line Header

Tags: macos, terminal, nano, pathfinder

I use nano (= pico) for editing git commits in my terminal window. I'm trying to use the terminal in PathFinder but this happens:

[image]

There are almost no settings for Path Finder. Is there anything I can do for my terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this works (in zshell):

`TERM=vt100; export TERM`